# How can I change tab size of python code in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autopep8

When I type the python code in vs code, indent tab size is **2**. But when I save the file, tab size is changed to **4**. I think this is because of **autopep8**.

How can I change the tab size, when I save the python code?

※ I already change editor.tabsize to 2

Comment: Do you see a tab button in the lower right corner?

Answer (score 2):

It's recommended to set '--indent-size' to change the autopep8 behavior. You can refer to [this](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/#configuration) page for details. But I can't make it works in this way, so I directly
make a change in autopep8.py(under site-packages which you installed the autopep8) file, at the line of 112 change "DEFAULT_INDENT_SIZE = 4" to "DEFAULT_INDENT_SIZE = 2". It works and it's the same to set '--indent-size' in logic.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure [autopep8](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/) to keep indent to two spaces. That way it won't undo how VS Code is inserting spaces for you.